# I want to copy from my bdo tag rtl text into ltr format

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file which contains `<bdo dir="rtl">hello</bdo>` this tag . So the output result is olleh . But the problem is when i copy this olleh word and paste it into any text editor it transform into left to right format such as hello. my question is is there any way so that i can copy me olleh word into left to right format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dir="rtl"` direction is only for display. If you open your devtools and look at the content, it's still ltr format, so when you copy it, it's still `hello`.

You could do a bit of javascript magic to reverse the string, and then place it back into your element:

```
const bdo = document.getElementsByTagName('bdo')[0];
const str = bdo.textContent;

bdo.textContent = reverseStr(str);

function reverseStr(str) {
  strArr = str.split('');

  strArr.reverse();

  reversedStr = strArr.join('');

  return reversedStr;

}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/dtfhzgbk/10/)

If you do this, you don't need the `dir` attribute at all.